# Parse a Mongo document using PHP

Tags: php, json, mongodb, symfony

I want to parse a mongo document using PHP and show the elements of this document in TWIG.
But I am stuck now.
This is a part of my document:

```
{"_id":
{"$id":"555f91d9fd2897e433000029"},
"users":[{"id":1735706894,
"id_str":"1735706894","name":"Funny Teen Quotes",
"screen_name":"D_Funny_Teens"},
{"id":1239321974,
"id_str":"1239321974",
"name":"Teen Quotes",
"screen_name":"SayingsOnTeens"} ...
```

And this is my function PHP:

```
   public function testAction()
{
    $m = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection');
    $db = $m->selectDatabase('test');
    $collection = $db->createCollection('tweets');
    $followcollection = $db->createCollection('followers');
    $follow  = $followcollection->findOne();
    $k = 0;
    foreach ($follow->users as $follower) {
        $returns[$k] = array(
            $follower->id,
            $follower->id_str
        );
        $k = $k+1;
    }

    $return = json_encode($return);
    return $this->render('ChartsBundle:Charts:test.html.twig', 
    array('returns'=> $returns
    )); }
```

My template twig:

```
{% for item in return %}
 <li>{{ returns.id }}</li>
 <li>{{ returns.id_str }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
```

I get this error

```
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: Suggestion: you are attempting to parse JSON from MongoDB using PHP. The [tag:mongodb] and [tag:php] tags are helpful in this case.

Comment: And what's the error? And why are you json encoding the `$return`? Have you proved, you get an json string instead an array from the mongodb driver?

Comment: @Paziツ I get this error   "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"  and I used the json encode just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try maybe:

```
(...)


$follow  = (object) $followcollection->findOne();
$k = 0;
foreach ($follow->users as $arrFollower) {
    $follower = (object)$arrFollower;
    $returns[$k] = (object)array(
        $follower->id,
        $follower->id_str
    );
    $k = $k+1;
}


(...)
```

Comment: I tried it but i got this error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$users`

Comment: ` $follower->id` Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Sorry I think I understand now. Please try again with the updated answer if you like :)

Comment: i get a syntax error `Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')'`

Comment: Thnx @T_G,  i have modified ur answer  a little bit  `foreach ($follow->users as $follower) {
            $followe = (object) $follower;
            $returns[$k] = (object)array(
                $followe->id ,
                $followe->id_str
    );`   and it work, thnx a lot

Comment: No problem. Glad could help at least a little. I'll also modify mine then.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html). This way you can work with regular PHP objects.

Comment: what i understood is that i must create an instance of a model to represent my document in the collection but my document is very huge that it seems impossible to decelerate  all the items, so please advice?